# Navbar transition height on hover using CSS3/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-transitions

I have been pulling my hair out for a while, and I now feel it's time to ask the question.  I am trying to put an effect on the `#navBar` (parent) but only when the `#competitionsButton` (child) is hovered.

The `navBar` holds all the buttons, and currently the transition only works when the whole `navBar` is hovered.

Is there a way using **Javascript** that can sort this problem.

HTML:

```
<div id="navBar">

    <div class="spacer"></div>

    <a href="index.html"><div id="homeButton"></div></a>

    <a href="index.html"><div id="howItWorksButton"></div></a>

    <a href="index.html"><div id="aboutButton"></div></a>

    <a href="index.html"><div id="competitionsButton"></div></a>

    <a href="index.html"><div id="contactUsButton"></div></a>

    <a href="index.html"><div id="postCompButton"></div></a>

    <div id="spacer"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navBar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(../images/navBarTransitionBG.png) repeat;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}

#navBar:hover {
    background: url(../images/navBarTransitionBG.png) repeat;
    height: 180px;
}

.spacer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
}

#homeButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navButtons/home.png);
}

#homeButton:hover {
    background: url(../images/navButtons/homeUL.png);
}

#howItWorksButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navButtons/howitworks.png);
}

#howItWorksButton:hover {
    background: url(../images/navButtons/howitworksUL.png);
}

#aboutButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navButtons/about.png);
}

#aboutButton:hover {
    background: url(../images/navButtons/aboutUL.png);
}

#competitionsButton {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navButtons/competitions.png);
}

#competitionsButton:hover {
    background: url(../images/navButtons/competitionsUL.png);
}

#contactUsButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navButtons/contactus.png);
}

#contactUsButton:hover {
    background: url(../images/navButtons/contactusUL.png);
}

#postCompButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navButtons/postcomp.png);
}

#postCompButton:hover {
    background: url(../images/navButtons/postcompUL.png);
}
```

Most of the CSS up there is not needed for a solution but it should give you an idea of the structure. Both the **HTML** and **CSS** could be massively reduced I know using classes etc but it's just been a little project and I haven't tidied it up (Also, I'm still learning!).

So basically, I need to hover over the competitions button, which will extend the whole `navBar` from `40px` to `180px` and also change the background of the competitions button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot work on the parent behavior with pure css, yes you need a bit of JQuery :)

Have a look at this simplified Fiddle (i worked with background colors instead of images but it's the same):

http://jsfiddle.net/JB6Sf/

This is the jquery you need:

```
$('#competitionsButton').hover(function(){
   $('#navBar').animate({
       height: '180px'
   }, 500);
}, 
   function(){
    $('#navBar').animate({
      height: '40px'
     }, 500);
});
```